# IF within a WHILE (USE OF UNDEFINED CONSTANT)

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop, undefined

I have a suspended boolean for each member of staff. when displaying staff members in a table i want to show either the text "SUSPENDED" or "NOT SUSPENDED" rather than 1 or 0.

I keep receiving the error,
Notice: Use of undefined constant Staff_Suspension - assumed 'Staff_Suspension'
Im sure this is simple im fairly new to php, just stuck and dont want to waste anymore time trying to work this out and not get anywhere. help appreciated

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td> $row[Staff_ID] </td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td> $row[Staff_Forename] </td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td> $row[Staff_Surname] </td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td> $row[Staff_Email] </td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>";

        if ($row[Staff_Suspension] == 1){
            echo 'Suspended';
        } else if ($row[Staff_Suspension] == 0){
            echo 'Not Suspended';
        }

        echo "</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td> $row[Staff_Delete_Permissions] </td>\n";
    echo "\t</tr>\n";

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP manual? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php - You must quote strings used as array indices.

Comment: of course, thats what happens when u work till 2am. cheers

Answer (score 3):

You must quote the indexes. Otherwise, PHP assumes you've [defined a constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) named `Staff_Suspension`. If no such constant exists, it then assumes you meant to specify a string literal. Quoting takes away any guess work (and, hence, any notice):

```
if ($row['Staff_Suspension'] == 1) {
    echo 'Suspended';
} elseif ($row['Staff_Suspension'] == 0) {
    echo 'Not Suspended';
}
```

or, simplified:

```
echo $row['Staff_Suspension'] ? 'Suspended' : 'Not Suspended';
```

Comment: Why should you wrap it in quotes? This is something that should be a comment

Comment: @Daryl, the error message already describes why it must be in quotes (PHP first checks to see if you are referencing a constant).

Comment: The op has specified that he is new to PHP so I have included a rough outline as to why this is required, because of people who have been using PHP for a while know this problem, newbies might not understand why

Comment: I've added additional explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer:**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>". $row['Staff_ID'] ".</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>". $row['Staff_Forename'] ."</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>". $row['Staff_Surname']". </td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>". $row['Staff_Email'] ".</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>";

        if ($row['Staff_Suspension'] == 1){
            echo 'Suspended';
        } else if ($row['Staff_Suspension'] == 0){
            echo 'Not Suspended';
        }

        echo "</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>". $row['Staff_Delete_Permissions'] ".</td>\n";
    echo "\t</tr>\n";

}
```

**Roughly Explained**

The use of constants comes mainly from `define();`  which you do not require a variable for **constant values**

the reason you are being presented with this error comes from the lines:

```
    if ($row[Staff_Suspension] == 1){
        echo 'Suspended';
    } else if ($row[Staff_Suspension] == 0){
        echo 'Not Suspended';
    }
```

Because you are  specifying a key of an array by the name. You should wrap this in quotes, double or single is up to you.

Example of a constant:

```
define ('Name', 'ConstantValue');
echo Name;
```

This will output : `ConstantValue`

now, from reading the above:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

the link is a rough explination on constant values.

Now for your specific question.

`$row[Staff_Suspension]`  You have defined a constant value, since this is a  column name, this should be wrapped in quotes.

If you was specifying from the key number:  `$row[0];`  this is a different story which is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: What do you mean by ***mainly** comes from*?

Comment: After editing the snippet, there could have been other causes for this error. I forgot to add that note, compare my edit to the OPs original

Comment: I did compare it. Where else in his code could the error be triggered?

Comment: Twas my edit which showed, realized now that it's an unnecessary line.

Comment: Just to add something: you may use something like this `echo "\t\t<td>{$row['Staff_ID']}</td>\n";`